# Is this login procedure to my rest-api server somewhat secure?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Because this is a non-budget hobby project, i can't afford a certificate.
Lets just say https is not an option. But at least i can use RSA.
Altough this is a hobby project, i want to get the security as right as possible, regarding passwords and for now i only care about sensible data like passwords.

Login:

```
Client -> Server: I want to log in.
Server -> Client: Here is the public key.
Client -> Server: *username and encrypted pw*
Server -> Client: Great. Please create a keypair and send me a public key.
Client -> Server: Here is a public key
Server -> Client: *encrypts session id with the clients public key* Here is your session id!
Client: *decrypts session id with private*
Client: *deletes the keypair*
```

Doing literally anything that requires to be logged in:

```
Client -> Server: I want to send a chat message! *encrypts sessionId with public key*
Server: *decrypts sessionId with private* Ok, your message has been sent!
```

Or what about this different approach?

We have two keypairs:

```
key1: The servers main key. Private is on server. The same for everyone.
key2: The session key. Private is on client. Generated on login by client.
```

The client sends the rest-query with one argument which is in json format and contains every parameter needed.
Encrypted using: key1

The rest-response would be encrypted via key2.

Would this be secure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may have a look at the RSA method, which is designed exactly for such applikations.

Comment: thanks. i was talking about using RSA. But RSA won't do anything if you use it wrong. I was asking if i was using it right :D

Comment: For clarification: key1 and key2 are both key PAIRS each consisting of a private key and a public key? I can't see the differences between both approaches.

Comment: key1 is a keypair generated at server-boot. key1.pub is sent to every client.
key2 is a keypair generated by the client on every login. key2.pub is sent to server.

key1 is used for encryption client->server and key2 is used for encryption server->client

The difference would be that approach 2 would encrypt the whole query as a json string and approach 1 would just encrypt the password

Comment: Seems like the second approach would only be possible for small amounts of data since even RSA 4096 is limited to 501 characters

Answer (score 0):

> Because this is a non-budget hobby project, i can't afford a certificate. Lets just say https is not an option.

when it comes to that - you can just create your own CA (certificate authority) trusted in scope of the project and you are good to go.

There are as well multiple ways to get a free trusted certificate (e. g. Letsencrypt)

Usual reason for being unable to use TLS is slow low-level hardware (e. g. Arduino) where asymmetric operations would take very long time (unfeasible to use RSA). Or a school educative project. Otherwise you may want to reconsider.

> Would this be secure?

Short - no.
Long - depends - secure against what?

If you check the [TLS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) the protocol is doing a lot of things (check the certificate trust, create and sign ephemeral keypairs, session key agreement, setting up channels, ..) and for good reasons. Taking shortcuts would make your protocol usecure agaist different attack vectors, which are mitigated in every step or layer.

For start - your (first version) protocol would be vulnerable against a MiM (man in the middle) attack. Anyone could pose a false server. Using direct trust (fixed server keypair - I believe that's the different approach?) you mitigate that, but other issues stay unsolved.

> The client sends the rest-query with one argument which is in json format and contains every parameter needed. Encrypted using: key1

In theory it may work passing properly encrypted messages *when done properly*. You did not specify much details, so we cannot asses other factors (e. g. replay attack, integrity,..)

Passing the encrypted messages over an unsecure channel - that is already considered in the end-to-end encrypted messaging protocols (e. g. Signal protocol). You may have a look at theses / use the protocols to make your secure if you really must skip TLS.